# onChange in createElement not working. React

Tags: reactjs

Using react and tried to create an element with createElement.

```js
const inputForEnglish = document.createElement("input");
inputForEnglish.type = "text";
inputForEnglish.placeholder = "English";
inputForEnglish.dataset.answernumber = answers.children.length + 1;
inputForEnglish.dataset.textfield = "english";
inputForEnglish.onChange = (e) => detectAnswerChange(e);
```

The last line doesn't work. I have a function called "detectAnswerChange()" and it takes event as parameter. The onChange works completely fine when it's done directly to an element.

I also tried `inputForEnglish.onchange = "detectAnswerChange()"`, it doesn't work.

It creates the element and all the above things works completely fine, but the `inputForEnglish.onChange = (e) => detectAnswerChange(e);` doesn't work.

Comment: Your snippet does not contain any code that uses the React library, `document.createElement` is a feature of your browser. It also does not contain the section where you actually add this input element to the page. Could you provide more context?

Comment: the link to the codesandbox is broken

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/function-vbh8j1 . here is the function. if the link isn't broken. @thedude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
inputForEnglish.oninput=(e)=>{
    //runs when the input changes
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
inputForEnglish.onchange=(e)=>{
    //runs only when the input is out of focus
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

use oninput for inputs

Answer (score 1):

It's all small letters. Use this:

```
inputForEnglish.onchange = (e) => detectAnswerChange(e);
```